# Add a span to a substring / part of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, split, var

I need to create a span around "8:00" so I can change its color.   Obviously I can't edit the actual html.

```
<span class="foo">The time is 8:00</span>
```

I was able to split it at the right spot:

```
var justTheTime= $('.foo').text().split('The time is')[1];
```

but can't figure out how to add the span around it.   Help?

```
var withStyles = $('<span style="color:red">'+onlyTheDate+'</span>');
$(".foo").replace(justTheTime,withStyles);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.replace()` is not a jQuery function; it is a JavaScript one. Also, you appear to be trying to add an undefined variable `onlyTheDate` instead of `justTheTime` - I've corrected this in my example.

What you could do is use **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**, and simply insert the text before the time manually. Note that you'll want to wrap `The time is` in its own `<span>`:

```js
var justTheTime = $('.foo').text().split('The time is')[1];
var withStyles = $('<span>The time is</span><span style="color:red">' + justTheTime + '</span>');
$('.foo').replaceWith(withStyles);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="foo">The time is 8:00</span>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The `replace()` method operates on strings, not jQuery elements.

Use a regular expression to replace the contents of the span, and use `.html()` to update it.

```
$('.foo').html(function(i, oldtext) {
    return oldtext.replace(/The time is (.*)/, 'The time is <span style="color:red">$1</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for a string formated as a time `/(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})/g` this will replace all items with a color, so if you have more than one date it will replace them all, and not just one like this:

```js
$('.foo').html(
    $('.foo').text().replace(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})/g, '<span class="red">$1:$2</span>')
)
```

```css
.red {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="foo">The time is 8:00</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```js
var justTheTime = $('.foo').text().split('The time is')[1];
var spanText = "The time is <span style='color:red'>"+ justTheTime +"</span>";
$('.foo').html(spanText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="foo">The time is 8:00</span>
```